# no me inserta array en base de datos en php

Tags: php, mysql

de nuevo tengo el problema, tengo dos array y cuando quiero insértalos en la base de datos no me los inserta, en mi localhost si anda ok, pero en el webserver donde tengo alojada la pagina no!. Tampoco me da ningun error, solo no ingresa los datos

este es la pagina que realiza la insercion:

```
<?php 
include "funcion/conexion.php";

if (isset($_REQUEST['sumartodos'])) {
    $etapa = $_POST['etapa'];
    $pntdis = $_POST['pntdis'];
    $pntdisid = $_POST['pntdisid'];

}
for ($i=0; $i<count($pntdisid); $i++) { 
    $tpntdisid = $pntdisid[$i];
    $tpntdis = $pntdis[$i];

$sql = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO puntos (ciclistaid,etapa,puntosdis) VALUES (?,?,?)");
$res = $sql->execute([$tpntdisid,$etapa,$tpntdis]);

if ($res) {
    echo "Datos ok";
}else{
    echo "datos NO ingresados";
}
}
```

esta es la estructura de la bd:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En la bd ya probe usando INT o VARCHAR y no cambia nada..

Alguno me puede dar una mano..

Muchas gracias

Comment: no estas pasando el tipo de dato, luego de prepare... te recomiendo leer el manual de [prepare](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.prepare.php) donde encontraras varios ejemplos.

Comment: @Bryro, probablemente esté usando PDO y el funcionamiento es diferente.

Comment: ¿Aparece el mensaje "datos No ingresados"? Seguramente es porque los campos de la tabla no tienen valor por defecto y no admiten NULL, por lo que deberías especificarlos todos al insertar, excepto ID, que es autoincrementable.

Comment: En áreas huérfanas en tu código, no estableces ningún control en ellas y por tanto no podrás saber con exactitud el motivo del fallo. Por ejemplo, del `if (isset($_REQUEST['sumartodos'])) {` pasas a insertar sin verificar nada más. Si alguna de las variables no debería estar vacía ni nula deberías verificar su estado. La inserción podría fallar por otros motivos, como clave duplicada por ejemplo. Para ver el error exacto, puede poner esto **temporalmente** en el `else`, así te dirá por qué falla la consulta: **`var_dump($db->errorInfo());`**

Comment: @Triby gracias! era el problema que estan en no null y algunos tenian q ser null.. ahora si anda!!

Comment: @A.Cedano, gracias por la info, ya agregue el "else" para obtener mas info, pero se soluciono con el tema de los campos null

Comment: Me alegro de que lo hayas resuelto. Cuando hay valores obligatorios debes controlar que esos valores tengan datos antes de pasar a la inserción. Es más de lo mismo, falta un poco de rigor en el código. Cuando programas debes controlar todo lo que pueda salir mal dando una respuesta adecuada. Debes verificar los no null, debes verificar la conexión, debes verificar los errores. Una de las principales tarea de un programador es pensar todo lo que podría salir mal para salir al paso y encontrar una respuesta o al menos indicar al usuario que corrija lo que hizo mal.